# About SKphysicsbody func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicsbody

Here is my code:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

  print("contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask:::\(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask)")
  print("contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask:::\(contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask)")
  print("contact.bodyA.isDynamic:::\(contact.bodyA.isDynamic)")
  print("contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask:::\(contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)")
  print("contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask:::\(contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask)")
  print("contact.bodyB.isDynamic:::\(contact.bodyB.isDynamic)")
```

and I got the result:

> contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask:::1 
>   contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask:::9
>   contact.bodyA.isDynamic:::true contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask:::5
>   contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask:::8 contact.bodyB.isDynamic:::false

I found the contact nodes are not collected by its categoryBitMask and contactTestBitMask. I mean A's categoryBitMask not match B's contactTestBitMask, but their contact can be detect.

Somebody tell me why, and how can I optimize the SKPhysicsContact.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and edit your post.

Comment: Though I am not a native English speaker, I will do my best to improve myself. Thanks a lot, Zydnar.